# Formatting a cell based on another cell having data

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-formatting

I am looking to do the following:

If B12 contains any data and C12 is blank fill in C12 with a red or yellow color.

If B12 is blank then C12 also stays clear/Blank.

Comment: Is conditional formatting not an option? "with a red or yellow color" - how do you choose between red or yellow?

Comment: I haven't been able to write a formula that works.  I believe it is finding the correct syntax to complete an if than statement.  I am unfamiliar with VB for a macro and excel syntax to write a working format.  It doesn't have to be red or yellow both just one to call out a cell.  If B12 has data I need the operator to also enter information into c12.  Something to call the attention to operator that there is a missing data point.

Comment: The formula you need is `=AND(B12<>"",C12="")`.

Comment: Thank you! That was pretty easy.  I wasn't using the AND formula and probably trying to over complicate it.  Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional formatting rule based on the formula:

```
=AND(B12<>"",C12="")
```

[image]